# How can I interpret a multiply-quantified statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, formal-languages, quantifiers

∃ x ∈ R such that ∀ y ∈ R, x + y = 0.
Can anyone help me rewrite this statement in plain english without symbols or variables?
So far I have "There exists a real number whose number and other number is equal to zero."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a nasty example and an excellent demonstration of the expressive power of variables (never mind logical quantifiers). Here's my best go:

> *There exists a real number that yields zero when added to any other real number.*

Comment: Along the same lines, "There exists a number which is an additive inverse of everything."

Comment: @LeeMosher: nice suggestion, but I think you'd have to define additive inverse in "plain English": "where one number is said to be an additive inverse of another if their sum is zero". $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: In verbose mode:  For every real number there exists a real number that is the negative of the first number.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: another nice suggestion, but you need to say "a negative" not "the negative" and you need to define that term. "where one number is said to be a negative of another if their sum is zero".

Comment: I don't think it gets any better, without introducing new terms not present in the sentence, such as "inverse" or "negative" (which then beg for definition). Your English says just what the FOL sentence says, no more no less, & as idiomatically as possible.